# Setting file meta data on .mpkg packages generated in PackageMaker (Mac OS X)

Tags: macos, file, installation, metadata, packagemaker

I am generating my installer file (.mpkg) using PackageMaker and would like to add things like version and copyright info to the .mpkg file, such that they are viewable via "Get Info" in the Mac OS X finder.

Is there a way to do this?